# How can I convert these numerical data into categorical data?

Tags: python, data-analysis, categorical-data

[image]

I want to conver the quality data into three categories. Low,medium and High with respect to two lowest value,intermidiate value and two highest value? I am new in python. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet with the data you receive as a Python object rather than the picture of a table?

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('csv',sep='\;', header=None).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"\"",""))
data.columns = data.iloc[0]
data.drop(index=0, inplace=True)

X= data.iloc[:,-1:]

X contains the values

Comment: What is the value of X? If you can include that in the main post it will make it easier for others to help.

Comment: X contains the values showed in the Image